# Closure of infinite set in finite complement topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I just asked a question to know if a proof using "or" to make a justification was valid logically.

Here is an example of my confusion.

Show that if $A$ is an infinite subset of $X$, then $\bar A=X$ in the  finite complement topology.

Here was my proof. Let $x \in X, U$ be an open set containing $x$.If $U=X$, then $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$. Suppose $U \neq X$. Then $U=X-S$ for some finite set $S$. Consider $A \cap (X-S)$. Then this intersection is nonempty (here is where I am unsure if this is correct) otherwise $A$ or $X-S$ would have to be finite.(A would be finite since $A \subset S$ if the intersection is empty, however I noticed the second statement is not necessarily true). So $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$ for each open set $U$, and since $x$ was arbitrary, $\bar A=X$.

So the statement "otherwise,..." is my justification for the contradiction that will arise if $(X-S) \cap A = \varnothing$. So I want to know if including the not necessarily true statement $X-S$ would have to be finite, ruins the validity of my proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the assertion that

> if $A\cap(X\setminus S)=\varnothing$, then either $A$ is finite, or $X\setminus S$ is finite

is technically true, because in fact one can conclude that $A$ must be finite, but in ordinary mathematical writing it will be understood to mean that there are two ways in which $A\cap(X\setminus S)=\varnothing$ can be true, $A$ finite or $X\setminus S$ finite, that both can occur, and that they exhaust the possibilities. But the fact that $A$ is infinite does not imply that its complement is finite, so the fact that $A$ and $X\setminus S$ are disjoint doesn’t mean that at least one must be finite.

Fortunately, the argument can be fixed quite easily. Let $x\in X$, and let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$. Then $U=X\setminus S$ for some finite $S\subseteq X$, so

$$A\cap U=A\cap(X\setminus S)=(A\cap X)\setminus S=A\setminus S\ne\varnothing\,,$$

since $A$ is infinite.

Note that there is no need to consider the case $U=X$ separately: that’s simply $U=X\setminus S$ for $S=\varnothing$.

Comment: I think my statement was $A \cap (X-S)=\varnothing \implies A$or $X-S$ is finite. Would this statement not make the argument correct?

Comment: you wrote not equal to $\varnothing$

Comment: @kevinfirme: Oops! I didn’t even notice that I’d written $\ne$. Fixed now; thanks.

Comment: I thought since $A \cap (X-S)= \varnothing$ then $A \subset S$. Since $A$ is a subset of a finite set it must be finite. Why is this assertion incorrect?

Comment: @kevinfirme: That’s essentially the argument that I made in my answer; had you said that, you’d have been okay. The problem is with the other alternative: the fact that $A$ is infinite does not imply that its complement is finite.

Comment: I thought if I had said "and" it would have been incorrect but I know that true or false implies true. So I thought I could potentially have gotten away with saying the second part, which is incorrect. That is why I asked a question previously about this. Why can't I get away with stating the true statement or the false, and get away with it?

Comment: @kevinfirme: Yes, the disjunction is true, but for what might be called an accidental reason: it’s true because one of the disjuncts is always true. At best it’s misleading and makes the reader wonder whether the writer actually understood what’s going on. I’ll modify the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: I was just wondering if I could be severely marked wrong for this on an exam. If I get marked off, could I try and argue that the statement is true, so the proof is not flawed?That's all I need to know and then it's clear.

Comment: @kevinfirme: If I were following my usual practice and scoring it out of $10$, I’d probably give it $6$ or $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not say: If $A$ is infinite, it cannot be contained in a finite subset and the **only** infinite closed subset is $X$ itself. So $\overline{A}=X$, and $A$ is dense.

Comment: I really like this one! (+1)